# Why cannot I directly access property ".SingleAsync().Property"?

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

My test code:

```
using (var db = new MyDbContext())
{
  string id = "";
  string pictureUrl = db.UserProfile.Single(x => x.Id == id).PictureUrl; //valid syntax

  var user = await db.UserProfile.SingleAsync(x => x.Id == id); //valid syntax
  string _pictureUrl = user.PictureUrl; //valid syntax
}
```

My problem is: I cannot directly declare `pictureUrl` like this:

```
string pictureUrl = await db.UserProfile.SingleAsync(x => x.Id == id).PictureUrl;
```

I've tried to do that, it threw me error message:

> `'Task<UserProfileViewModels>'` does not contain a definition for
>   `'PictureUrl'` and no extension method `'PictureUrl'` accepting a first
>   argument of type `'Task<UserProfileViewModels>'` could be found.

Can you explain me why?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`SingleAsync` returns a `Task<UserProfileViewModels>`. That task doesn't have your property on it. You need to await the task to get back the actual `UserProfileViewModels` result

To tell the compiler you want the property of the result and not the task you need to surround the await expression in a parenthesis:

```
string pictureUrl = (await db.UserProfile.SingleAsync(x => x.Id == id)).PictureUrl;
```